# Persistir currentUser do firebase com React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

Essa função é disparada ao clicar no botão de Login:

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
.then(() => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => {
      firebase.database().ref('/admins').once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        const admins = _.map(snapshot.val(), (val, uid) => {
          return { ...val, uid };
        });
        if (admins.some((item) => item.s_email === email)) {
          typeAdmin(dispatch);
        } else typeStudent(dispatch);
        loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user);
      });
    }).catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
  });
};
};
```

**Comportamento Atual**

Ao sair do aplicativo e voltar é necessário relogar para acessar os dados do currentUser.

**Comportamento Esperado**

Ao sair do aplicativo manter o currentUser da sessão e ao voltar nada ter sido perdido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já passei por isso e consegui resolver de uma maneira simples:

```
isLogged() {
    if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
        //Esta logado então faça algo ...
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    isLogged();
}
```

O metodo isLogged() deve ser chamado após a inicialização do firebase ter sido feita ou irá gerar um erro.

Comment: Muito obrigado, essa solução deu certo. Optei por armazenar o status do usuário por AsyncStorage, assim mantenho as informações mesmo que o aplicativo seja fechado. Eu votei -1 no seu comentário sem querer e não tô conseguindo mudar. Valeu pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Estou tentando fazer dessa forma, mas sempre que fecho o app o `currentUser` fica `NULL`

```
       firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(() => {
          firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user, pass).then(loginUserSuccess)
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('erro');
           })
        })
```

esse `console.log()` abaixo mostra null sempre que abro o APP

```
  isLogged() {
    console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
    if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
      this.props.navigation.replace('Fazendas');
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.isLogged();
  }
```